# convert xslt2.0 to xslt1.0 syntax

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT and i got to understand from my team that the current xml parser we have supports only version 1.0. I would need help here to convert my current xslt 2.0 code to version 1.0

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>id|parent_id</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Package">
        <xsl:variable name="b-id" select="Business_ID" />
        <!-- TPFC data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="TPFC">
            <xsl:variable name="total_level" select="count(.//.//Parent)+1"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="prod-family">
                <xsl:with-param name="total_level" select="$total_level"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="b_id" select="$b-id"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:for-each select="//Parent">
                <!-----Question 2------->
                <xsl:call-template name="prod-family">
                    <xsl:with-param name="total_level" select="$total_level"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="b_id" select="$b-id"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-----Question 1------->
<xsl:template name="prod-family">
    <xsl:param name="total_level"/>
    <xsl:param name="b_id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="reverse(.//Parent/Name), translate(Name,' ','')" separator="_" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="reverse(.//Parent/Name)" separator="_" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

XML For the above is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Package ID="1122" BusinessID="001233" Version="19.0.2" xsi:type="Doms">
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Description> Desc sample</Description>
        <Category>54</Category>
        <Business_ID>001233</Business_ID>
        <TPFC ID="76" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
            <Name>AM</Name>
            <Parent ID="11d" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
                <Description>Mob1</Description>
                <Name>Mob1</Name>
                <Parent ID="12F" xsi:type="TPFC" Pattern="Th_Branch">
                    <Description>Mob2</Description>
                    <Name>Mob2</Name>
                </Parent>
            </Parent>
        </TPFC>
    </Package>
</Root>
```

This is the result

```
  | id           |  parent_id | 
  | Mob2_Mob1_AM |  Mob2_Mob1 |
  | Mob2_Mob1    | Mob2      | 
  | Mob2         |           |
```

In the above example, I have implemented the concatenation using XSLT 2.0 in two places (check template - **prod-family** ) where

**id** - Concatenation of all names from its root parent to current name in the below example it will be Mob2_Mob1_AM
**parent_id** - Concatenation of all parent names from its root parent

1. Can anyone help me out on how to implement concat using for-each in XSLT 1.0 version for the above two cases
2. Is call-template along with params supported in XSLT 1.0 as well?

Comment: Sounds more like a work order than a question. If you have a **specific** problem, then ask about that - and reduce the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate that problem.

Comment: Agreed, I should have asked my question specifically , Now I have updated my question above. Kindly check

Comment: Note, the expression `count(.//.//Parent)` is hopelessly misguided in both 1.0 and 2.0. It's just a longwinded and potentially very inefficient way of saying `count(.//Parent)`. (Inefficient because for every descendant, you collect all its descendants, and then eliminate all the duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance the only 2.0 constructs here are the call on `reverse()`, and the use of `xsl:value-of/@separator`. These are used together. You should be able to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//Parent/Name | ./Name">
  <xsl:sort select="-position()"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">_</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```